# How to dynamically render <router-link> or <a> in Vue depending on whether the link is exrternal or internal?

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, hyperlink, vue-router

```html
<template>
  <component
    :is="type === 'internal' ? 'router-link' : 'a'"
    :to="type === 'internal' ? link : null"
    :href="type !== 'internal' ? link : null"
  >
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SiteLink extends Vue {
  @Prop({
    validator: (value: string) =>
      ["external", "internal"].includes(value)
  })
  private readonly type!: string;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  private readonly link!: string;
}
</script>
```

Above is a Vue component where it will render a link. I have stripped out anything not relevant to the problem (I.e. `rel`, `target`, `class`, etc.).

**Understanding** - My understanding of Vue Router is that `<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>` and `<a href="/about">About</a>` will both render as`<a href="/about">About</a>` in the DOM, with a difference being the `<router-link>` version will give the link the SPA functionality (I.e. doesn't load a new page, it dynamically renders a component).

**Expected** - When `type="internal"`, it will render the `<router-link>` version. When `type="external"`, it will render the `<a>` version.

```html
<site-link type="external" link="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</site-link>

Will render

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

```html
<site-link type="internal" link="/about">About</site-link>

Will render

<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>

Which is then handle by VueRouter to render

<a href="/about">About</a>
```

**Actual** - When `type="internal"`, a `<a>` with **no** `href` rendered in the DOM. When `type="external"`, it renders as expected.

```html
<site-link type="external" link="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</site-link>

Will render

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

```html
<site-link type="internal" link="/about">About</site-link>

Will render

<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>

Which is then handle by VueRouter to render

<a>About</a> <!-- Notice there is no href -->
```

Any ideas how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Why can't you use `router-link` for both?

Comment: I attempted that suggestion, always using `router-link` for both internal and external links and it seems, for external links, it prefixes `localhost:8080` (or whatever the root URL is) the `link` that is passed as a prop.

Comment: Please check out my proposed solution below and let me know if it helps?

Comment: OK thank you. Let me give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation includes an example of how to do this now.

- [Extending RouterLink](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/extending-router-link.html)

Their approach is to create a custom template that handles external links.

Answer (score 5):

The better and cleaner approach:

```
  <router-link v-if="type === 'internal' :to="link">
    <slot />
  </router-link>
  <a v-else :ref="link"> <slot /> </a>
```

You can use `v-if` in root element so it solves you the case

Or may be you just missed path part?

```
  <component
    :is="type === 'internal' ? 'router-link' : 'a'"
    :to="type === 'internal' ? { path: link } : null"
    :href="type !== 'internal' ? link : null"
  >
    <slot />
  </component>
```

Comment: This was going to be my second approach, however my other properties, such as `rel`, `target`, `class`, etc. would be duplicated between them. I was trying not to duplicate properties.

Comment: Updated answer, check now

Comment: Tried the second option, doesn't seem to render anything now.

Comment: This is a really good alternative solution with the only downfall being duplicating properties, such as `rel`, `class` and `target` in the `<router-link>` and again in the `<a>`. If a clean method can be suggested where properties are not duplicated, I'd be happy to make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @JDomleo It would've been helpful if you'd add the expected output for both "internal" and "external" anchors, e.g. which one to take which attributes (or if it's okay to make them both have everything). I'm assuming that these stripped out attributes are meant for the external link, but I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: @YomS. Please see revised question with updated expected and actual code examples.

Answer (score 1):

> ...with a difference being the `<router-link>` version will give the link the SPA functionality (I.e. doesn't load a new page, it dynamically renders a component).

By not loading a new page, I suppose you mean it does not reload the page. And yes, it doesn't because the `onclick` handler actually gets assigned to a function that [does a `preventDefault`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/bc41f67e99aeeb5306da7e8d6b2f2f41649196f7/src/components/link.js#L165) (preventing page redirection) while [pushing a new entry into the history stack](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort).

If you take a look at [the API reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0), the most noticeable thing `<router-link>` does for you is it toggles between the [`active-class`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class)es depending on the active/current route.

So, that being said, you could do your dynamic `<a>`nchor rendering inside the default slot via [the `v-slot`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0); because at this point, the `href` slot prop would have been a resolved URL which you can then safely bind to the DOM `href` attribute.

---

### Edit

Added an example (untested).

```html
<router-link
  :to="link"
  v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }">
  <a
    :class="isActive ? 'your-custom-class' : 'anything'"
    :href="type !== 'internal' ? href : 'javascript:void(0);'"
    @click="customNavigate(navigate.bind($event))">
    <slot></slot>
  </a>
</router-link>
```

Where the `customNavigate` handler could be something like:

```js
{
  methods: {
    customNavigate(navigate) {
      if (this.type === 'internal') {
        navigate();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can basically add any attributes on the in-component anchor tag based on the slot props, like navigating in certain ways, adding special classes, depending on your use case.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I've understood this correctly. Could you possibly an example from the code in the question? I have attempted the above suggestion, but I found it difficult. Not sure if it's because I've misunderstood.

Comment: @JDomleo Sure, gimme a min.

Comment: Thanks @Yom S. This is the closest I'm looking for. However, not exactly.

Comment: @JDomleo Since we both agree that `<router-link>` resolves to `<a>`, is there any specific reason why we can't jump straight to the final output (`<a>`)? Isn't the link/href the essential part here?